# How to pass translations from a module to a smarty template in prestashop?

Tags: module, smarty, translation, prestashop

I'm building a module, and have somethins like this:

```
$custom_menu = '<ul class="main-menu custom-menu">'.
  '<li class="collections">' . $this->l("Collections") . $this->get_collections_menu($collections) . '</li>'.
  '<li class="styles">' . $this->l("Styles") . $this->get_styles_menu($collections) . '</li>'.
  '<li class="pearls">' . $this->l("Pearls") . $this->get_pearls_menu($collections_category_link) . '</li>'.
  '<li class="prices">' . $this->l("Prices") . $this->get_prices_menu($collections_category_link) . '</li>'.
  '<li class="categories hide-for-large-up">' . $this->l("Categories") . $this->get_categories_menu() . '</li>'.
'</ul>';

$this->context->smarty->assign('custom_menu', $custom_menu);
```

It all goes fine, menu will show up. My problem is with translations: I cannot find them in backoffice to edit. What's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I've just found the solution: strings MUST be delimited with single quotes, not double quotes. So instead of this:

```
'<li class="collections">' . $this->l("Collections") . $this->get_collections_menu($collections) . '</li>'
```

use this:

```
'<li class="collections">' . $this->l('Collections') . $this->get_collections_menu($collections) . '</li>'
```

In other words: `$this->('your string')` is fine.

Then you'll find the fields to translate on the backoffice translations panel, under the 'module translations' translation type.

And no matter where in the module you'll place the `l()` functions. Constructor, hooks, string concatenations, everywhere is fine.

Answer (score 0):

For translate php

```
$this->l('Text')
```

For translate tpl

```
{l s='Text' mod='Name Module'}
```

In your case

```
'<li class="collections">{l s='Collections' mod='Name Module'}'
```

Comment: No I already tried but passing it to a smarty var from a module, it gets reported as is, so you end up seeing {l s='Collections' mod='Name Module'} in your page, not interpreted/parsed.